# How to calculate the frequency of word in Zipf's law?

Tags: collections, task, frequency, words

There are 4 different words a, b, c, d in a collection where their frequency order is a > b > c > d. The total number of tokens in this collection is 1500. Using [Zipf's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law), what are the frequencies of the four words?

Is there any formula for Zipf's law?

I studied that the most frequent will occur approximately twice as often as the second most frequent word in Zipf's law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I humbly direct you to [the wikipedia article on Zipf's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law),

Formally, let:

- N be the number of elements;
- k be their rank;
- s be the value of
  the exponent characterizing the distribution.

Zipf's law then predicts that out of a population of N elements, the frequency of elements of rank k, *f(k;s,N)*, is:

[image: f(k;s,N)=\frac{1/k^s}{\sum_{n=1}^N (1/n^s)}.]

There you go. There's your formula for the frequency of a word.